# Feature from installed msi becomes advertised after major-upgrade of another msi

Tags: windows-installer

I have two msi A, B. These msi share some component between each other, however have different features.

case:

- A and B installed. Features has state "Local"
- Then I install a newer version of A (major-upgrade).
- After that feature from B becomes advertised and I can't do a proper
  major upgrade for B.

I can't find any hint from upgrade log of A, why feature from B become advertised.

Comment: Seems related: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2006/01/23/why-is-my-feature-advertised/

Answer (score 1):

When you do major upgrade, the original msi A gets uninstalled, then a new version is installed. The newer version has other components, which is quite expected, and thus some components of msi B are missing on the system.

Can you reproduce the same issue by simply removing msi A?

I can guess that the component in question from old and new version share the same path, thus some files that msi B uses are replaced with newer versions.